# JS looping a folder of images, preload them and assign to an array?

Tags: javascript

I have a folder named "img" and i want to use js to look up the folder and find all the image files (jpg,JPG or png) and preload them and assign them to an array.

Can this be done in terms of looking up a folder like that on my server? Or does client code not allow you to loop through files in a folder?

Comment: That would be a major security hole.

Comment: @cdesrosiers - Not for static read-only items.  Directory pages have been around since the NCSA servers (I don't remember CERN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have directory browsing enabled, you could parse the automatically generated directory page.  It would be difficult to write that here, without knowing what your directory output looks like.

Otherwise, you need to write server code.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that with client side JS. You have to know the exact name of the resource you're looking for - there's no way to "browse".